# laravel8 - why my $request always return false

Tags: php, laravel, middleware

I'm trying to practice about middleware in Laravel 8, I created Middleware file by terminal, registed file in Kernel and call middleware in route but the problem is when i try to pass paremeter from url by localhost:8000/admin/?user=admin it's always redirect to the about page

Here's my middleware code, it's CheckAdmin.php

```
namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class CheckAdmin
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
    {
        if($request->user == 'admin'){
            return redirect('/admin');
        } else {
            return redirect('/about');
        }
       return $next($request);
    }
}
```

Here's Karnel.php

```
namespace App\Http;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel as HttpKernel;

class Kernel extends HttpKernel
{
    /**
     * The application's global HTTP middleware stack.
     *
     * These middleware are run during every request to your application.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $middleware = [
        // \App\Http\Middleware\TrustHosts::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\TrustProxies::class,
        \Fruitcake\Cors\HandleCors::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\PreventRequestsDuringMaintenance::class,
        \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ValidatePostSize::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\TrimStrings::class,
        \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ConvertEmptyStringsToNull::class,
    ];

    /**
     * The application's route middleware groups.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $middlewareGroups = [
        'web' => [
            \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
            \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
            \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
            // \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\AuthenticateSession::class,
            \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
            \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
            \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
        ],

        'api' => [
            // \Laravel\Sanctum\Http\Middleware\EnsureFrontendRequestsAreStateful::class,
            'throttle:api',
            \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
        ],
    ];

    /**
     * The application's route middleware.
     *
     * These middleware may be assigned to groups or used individually.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $routeMiddleware = [
        'auth' => \App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
        'auth.basic' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth::class,
        'cache.headers' => \Illuminate\Http\Middleware\SetCacheHeaders::class,
        'can' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authorize::class,
        'guest' => \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated::class,
        'password.confirm' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\RequirePassword::class,
        'signed' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ValidateSignature::class,
        'throttle' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests::class,
        'verified' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\EnsureEmailIsVerified::class,
        'CheckAdmin' => \App\Http\Middleware\CheckAdmin::class
    ];
}
```

Here's web.php

```
use App\Http\Controllers\AboutController;
use App\Http\Controllers\AdminController;
use App\Http\Controllers\MemberController;
use App\Http\Middleware\CheckAdmin;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Web Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register web routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| contains the "web" middleware group. Now create something great!
|
*/

Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Route::get('/about', [AboutController::class, 'index']);
Route::get('/admin', [AdminController::class, 'index'])->middleware('CheckAdmin');
Route::get('/member', [MemberController::class, 'index']);
```

Comment: side ntoe: you will be creating a recursive loop of redirects when you resolve that issue with the input

Answer (score 0):

The method `user()` is reserved in the request:

```php
$request->user() //returns an instance of the authenticated user
```

Also, setting admin as a url parameter is unsafe, everyone can add that to the url to become an admin, you should rather work with tokens or with dedicated columns/ tables in the database to verify an admin,

Answer (score 0):

You should check the below condition in your AdminController, not in the middleware
here I am providing some examples:
my Middleware example:

```
namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Auth;

class AdminMiddleware
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
    {
        if (Auth::user()->user_type == 'admin'){
            return $next($request);
        }else{
            return redirect()->route('home');
        }
    }
}
```

LoginController Example:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Models\User;
use App\Models\Page;
use Session;
use Auth;
use Hash;
use DB;


class LoginController extends Controller
{
    public function adminLogin(){
        return view('login');
    }

    public function adminLogedin(Request $request){

        $message = array(
            'required.email'    =>  'This is required',
            'required.password' =>  'This is required',
        );
        $this->validate($request,[
            'email' =>  'required',
            'password'  =>  'required',
        ],$message);

        $email = $request->email;
        $pass = $request->password;

        if(Auth::attempt(['email' => $email, 'password' => $pass, 'status' => 1])){
            Session::flash('success','Welcome '.Auth::user()->name);
            return redirect()->route('dashboard');
        }else{
            Session::flash('error','Sorry! Try Again. It seems your login credential is not correct.');
            return redirect()->back();
        }

    }
}
```

I think it will help @Nico Haase
Comment if need any help.

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it

Comment: Sure @NicoHaase let me update my answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot sir, I'll follow your solution to improve myself.